# compare column A in google sheets by scripts. when match is correct then paste offset value in both side

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I comparing data from Sheet 00 and 01 by loops.
I'm working in VBA and that's my first steps in JavaScripts.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/176pTsstzHQ5FfhEvFJswQUidIGMGTi6jjkTavj2BQOQ/edit?usp=sharing

In output i have duplicate data. 
Right now, I try to find in logger.log some point to understood 
if I understood  I need to skip from loop after matching to next iterate.
I am asking for support what I do wrong in guiding me on the right way:) 
Thank You in advanced.

compare COL_A - to find - unique - in 2 sheets in a the some workbook.
 sheet00 is colected new data to compare with sheet 01. 
Problem is:  after matching find1,find2 - I have duplicated rows in output. 
 find_is_value_is_exist_then_paste_in_both_side

```
function abc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh_0=ss.getSheetByName("CA_SHEET_00")
  var lastRow=sh_0.getLastRow()
  var CA_Sheet_00= sh_0.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,12).getValues();
   Logger.log('LastRow 00_CA_SHEET'+' - row - '+lastRow);
  var sh_1=ss.getSheetByName("AA_01") 
  var lastRow_01=sh_1.getLastRow()
  var AA_01 = sh_1.getRange(2,1,lastRow_01-1,12).getValues();
   Logger.log('lastRow_01 AA_01'+' - row - '+lastRow_01);      
   var aaa = [];
   var bbb = [];
     i=0;
     j=0;  
    for (var i = 0; i < CA_Sheet_00.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < AA_01.length; j++) {        
        if(CA_Sheet_00[i][0]===AA_01[j][0]){  
         Logger.log('00'+CA_Sheet_00[i][0]+' - CA_SHEET_00 - row '+[i]);
         Logger.log('01'+AA_01[j][0]+' - AA_01 - row '+[j]);   
         aaa.push([CA_Sheet_00[i][11],CA_Sheet_00[3],AA_01[4],]);
         bbb.push([CA_Sheet_00[j][3],]);       
     sh_0.getRange(2+i,13,aaa.length,3).setValues(aaa);   // 00
     sh_1.getRange(2+j,13,bbb.length,1).setValues(bbb);  }} }}
```

after modification code by **Copper** it will be defined like that.
I just only separate output in column  as single (13,14,15)

```js
function abc() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName("CA_SHEET_00");
  var vA=sh0.getRange(2,1,sh0.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("AA_01") 
  var vB=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vB.length;j++) {        
      if(vA[i][0]==vB[j][0]){     
        sh0.getRange(2+i,13).setValue(Utilities.formatString('%s',vA[i][11]));  
        sh0.getRange(2+i,14).setValue(Utilities.formatString('%s',vA[i][3]));  
        sh0.getRange(2+i,15).setValue(Utilities.formatString('%s',vA[i][0])); 
        sh1.getRange(2+j,13).setValue(vA[i][3]);  
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what your question is but I think this is what you're trying to accomplish with your code.

```
function abc() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName("CA_SHEET_00");
  var vA=sh0.getRange(2,1,sh0.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("AA_01") 
  var vB=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vB.length;j++) {        
      if(vA[i][0]==vB[j][0]){     
        sh0.getRange(2+i,13).setValue(Utilities.formatString('%s,%s,%s',vA[i][11],vA[i][3],vB[i][4]));   
        sh1.getRange(2+j,13).setValue(vA[i][3]);  
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

If I totally missed the point, I apologize;

Comment: wow. I modificate a little bit Your code and i Have exactly what I need. I don't need to join string but it easy to separate output. Thank You Cooper.